# See what process last touched a file

Tags: linux, bash

On a linux box that there is some process regularly changing permissions on directories and files, roughly daily. This is not a process that I set up and I have no idea what it is.

I have root access and I can easily change permissions manually to get access back but it is a bit annoying.

Is there an way to see a list of processes that have last touched a file? Or alternatively how would I go about logging process activity on the file.

Comment: Would lsof help?  It lists all opened files and the processes that opened them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On a Fedora system, you can use:

```
sudo auditctl -p a -w /some/file  # monitor attribute changes to /some/file
```

It's in the `audit` package, if you don't have that installed, then `sudo yum install audit`

The output goes into `/var/log/audit/audit.log` in the form:

```
  type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1325185116.524:1133): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=671600 a1=241 a2=1b6 a3=9 items=1 ppid=26641 pid=26643 auid=501 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=1 comm="jmacs" exe="/usr/bin/joe" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
  type=CWD msg=audit(1325185116.524:1133):  cwd="/tmp"
  type=PATH msg=audit(1325185116.524:1133): item=0 name="/etc/passwd" inode=531545 dev=fd:01 mode=0100644 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0
```

It's a bit dense, but note the `msg=audit(###)` strings line up across multiple lines.

- Now that I actually read the manpage for the first time ever, I see some cautions about using `-Farch=b32`/`-Farch=b64`, so it seems that there is some possible weirdness about 32-bit-vs-64-bit syscalls, so if you don't get an audit hit, that might be why. I've never really seen this bit before, but I haven't really run any 32-bit processes since the Athlon era, so I can't speak to it very well.

Comment: On Debian/Ubuntu the required package is named `auditd`.

Comment: Yes - I played around with this for a while. It certainly answers my question above. auditctl seems like a pretty useful tool

Answer (score 3):

If you need to monitor changes to some file or directory, [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) might be helpful.

In bash there's [inotifywait](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/inotifywait.1.html) (you can find a nice example about how to use it [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5984639&postcount=3)), and in python (just in case you consider using it) there's a library called [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Going to go with the first answer as auditctl seems like a tool written to do this already.