# Copy a file every 60 seconds bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, cp

I have a thecus nas server, and they seem to do some tricky things to their templates to display their files, currently at boot I'm running a shell command to copy one file over another, so that It boots with my custom template, however after a certain amount of time (I'm not sure what this time is) it overwrites it again with the original and my custom template is gone.

Here is my current boot script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /customTemplates/login.tpl /www/img/templates/adm/login.tpl
```

Is there a way, to perform that copy command, say every 60 seconds? the login.tpl file is only 2kb, so I wouldn't think this could cause any problems.

Is there anything wrong with doing this, this way? Or is there another trick I could use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the general question, two ways to do this, put it in a while/sleep loop or use a crontab

**1)** while/sleep

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  cp -f /customTemplates/login.tpl /www/img/templates/adm/login.tpl
  sleep 60
done
```

**2)** crontab (preferred)

Run `crontab -e` and put the following line there

```
* * * * * cp -f /customTemplates/login.tpl /www/img/templates/adm/login.tpl
```

This will run the command every minute of every hour of every day of every month of every day of the week. (ergo every 60 seconds)

But, as [Aaron Digulla said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572456/3076724) it would be better to get to where it's pulling the config from and edit it there, rather then overwriting it every 60 seconds.

Comment: The cronjob worked fine! I also didn't know you could just put the cp command straight in there so you taught me something else, thankyou!

Comment: I'm not sure about the crontab but the while loop will copy every 60s + the time needed to execute the `cp` command (which can take much longer...)

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to find out where the NAS takes the original file from.

Execute this command to find possible candidates:

```
find / -name "login.tpl"
```

You can also use patterns: `"*login*"`

I suggest to use the quotes when you use patterns, otherwise it might match files in the local folder and the shell will then replace the name *before* it passes the argument to `find`.

To find out who changes the file, use `auditctl` ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672039/see-what-process-last-touched-a-file)).

Comment: I am pretty sure I have done this from the root already, but I'll let it go over night and hopefully it returns more results.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins Yes, assuming it has the same name.

Answer (score 0):

try the following solution:

```
chmod +x /tmp/test.sh
```

your script test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -f /customTemplates/login.tpl /www/img/templates/adm/login.tpl
```

then do:

```
touch /tmp/cronjob
echo "* * * * * ./test.sh" > /tmp/cronjob
/etc/init.d/crond/start
crontab /tmp/cronjob
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a throw-away, one time sort of solution, you can use the watch utility

```
watch -n 60 ./test.sh
```

runs ./test.sh every 60 seconds and echoes the output to stdout